# en pl/sql como contar el numero de registros de una tabla

Tags: plsql

En pl/sql, como contar el numero de lineas de una tabla y que luego me saque un mensaje

tengo x proveedores en la tabla de proveedores

Comment: No entendi muy bien tu pregunta, pero sera que deseas esto:
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM proveedores

Comment: Gracias Gerardo, pero esa instrucción deja el valor del count en una variable llamada total?. Perdona pero es que soy un novato. Eso si me vendria bien para hacer luego unas comparaciones de ese valor. Es así?

Comment: que tipo de comparaciones? para saber si te ayudamos con el pl.. o si te basta con la consulta de Gerardo, y a lo mucho meter el valor en un select into

Answer (score 1):

La función **count()**, te permite contar los registros de una tabla

Ademas puedes añadirle un **WHERE** a la consulta y te dará un conteo de un segmento de registros

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM datos
```